# Quickly create a new Firefox profile and load Firefox with it

Tags: windows-7, command-line, firefox, batch-file, firefox-profile

I want to be able to quickly create (and delete) Firefox profiles for testing purposes in Win 7 SP1.

To do this, I created a batch file with the single line:

```
firefox.exe -CreateProfile test && firefox.exe -profilemanager
```

*(I've simplified this for posting by removing the full path to the executable.)*

This works fine, but it leaves a DOS box open in the background that does not close until Firefox is closed.

Is there a way I can accomplish this without having a background process waiting for Firefox to be closed?

*(Back in the good ol' DOS days, you could manually add a <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> to the end of the last line in a batch file to terminate the batch file with the execution of the last command, but I haven't been able to get anything like that to work in Windows.)*

I would strongly prefer not to have to install any additional scripting languages.

**Bonus Points**: If you can find a way to cleanly delete a profile via a similar method.

**Update**: Out of curiosity, I tried just creating a shortcut link with the above command, but no workie.

Answer (score 2):

It should close automatically. If it does not, try this:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -CreateProfile test && start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -profilemanager
```

Comment: I don't know why, but sometimes that is working, and sometimes it is not.   Also, third-party explorers, like FreeCommander, seem to make it fail more often than Windows Explorer.

Comment: I think the problem is that `start` only covers the _first_ command, not the second one, so essentially you have both running at the same time and working depends on which one wins the race. Instead, only `start` the _last_ Firefox command.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I've edited the command based on grawity's information. Does it work every time now?

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the profile manager entirely:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set profile=%TEMP%\fxprofile
if exist "%profile%" rd/s/q "%profile%"
md "%profile%"
start firefox -profile "%profile%"
```

(As I'm not on Windows right now, I'm not sure if the `start` is even necessary)

Note, however, that Windows 7 *already has* several scripting runtimes other than `cmd.exe` – in particular, cscript (supporting JScript and VBScript) as well as PowerShell (able to load any .NET assembly).

Comment: Hmmm... that's an interesting idea.  There is a little more tidying up to do because Firefox creates profile folders in two different locations for each profile, but the idea itself looks very sound.  Thanks!

Comment: No – if you create the profile outside the default location, it will be self-contained.

Comment: Really?  That's an added bonus.